# What is the best way to write an insert code with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have recently learned Object Oriented Programming PHP, and I tried to test my knowledge on that, so I tried to write some queries by myself...

(Example practice: inserting new row, updating a row and deleting a row).

And here is of the templates that I've coded myself in order to *Insert New Row into database*:

```
class Register
{   
    protected $notice = array();
    private $_db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_db = new Connection();
        $this->_db = $this->_db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)
    {
        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($groups)&&!empty($level))
        {
            $chk1 = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM admins WHERE user_name = ?");
            $chk1->bindParam(1,$username);
            $chk1->execute();
            if($chk1->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                $notice['username_exists'] = "Try different username";
                return $this->notice;
            }else{
                $chk2 = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT email_address FROM admins WHERE email_address = ?");
                $chk2->bindParam(1,$email);
                $chk2->execute();
                if($chk2->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                    $notice['email_exists'] = "The email address that you have entered is already exists in database";
                    return $this->notice;
                }else{
                    $this->NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
                    $notice['success_message'] = "New admin was successfully added";
                    return $this->notice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)
    {
        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($groups)&&!empty($level))
        {
            $reg = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO admins (user_name, email_address, password_hash, group_admin, date_joined, admin_level) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
            $reg->bindParam(1,$username);
            $reg->bindParam(2,$email);
            $reg->bindParam(3,$password);
            $reg->bindParam(4,$groups);
            $reg->bindParam(5,$level);
            $reg->execute();
        }
    }
    public function getNotice()
    {
        return $this->notice;
    }
}
```

And I called this Class on index:

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $groups = $_POST['groups'];
    if($groups == "Administrator"){
        $level = 2;
    }else if($groups == "ContentCreatorBlog"){
        $level = 3;
    }else if($groups == "ContentCreatorShop"){
        $level = 4;
    }else if($groups == "ContentCreatorGallery"){
        $level = 5;
    }else if($groups == "Secretary"){
        $level = 6;
    }else if($groups == "SocialMediaManager"){
        $level = 7;
    }else if($groups == "Analyst"){
        $level = 8;
    }else{
        $level = Null;
    }
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $notice['email_validation'] = "The email that you have entered is not a valid one";
    }else{
        $registration = new Register();
        $notice[] = $registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);   
    }   
}
?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Add New Admin
            <small>You can add new admin here</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">addnewadmin.php</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box box-primary" id="myModal1">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Required Information</h3>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($notice['email_validation'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['email_validation'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    if(isset($notice['username_exists'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['username_exists'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    if(isset($notice['email_exists'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['email_exists'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    if(isset($notice['success_message'])) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='alert alert-success'>
                                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['success_message'].".
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="" data-tour-index="1" data-tour-title="Card Type" data-tour-description="A card will usually be one of multiple similar type items on a page.">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>User name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Temporary password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter password" name="pass" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Group admin</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="groups">
                                    <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                                    <option value="ContentCreatorBlog">Blog Content Creator</option>
                                    <option value="ContentCreatorShop">Shop Content Creator</option>
                                    <option value="ContentCreatorGallery">Gallery Content Creator</option>
                                    <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
                                    <option value="SocialMediaManager">Social Media Manager</option>
                                    <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            Visit <a href="https://zite.pouyavagefi.com/documentation/adminnew.php">admin new</a> documentation to know more about this page.
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

So shortly what it does is showing the form and take some information and assign to parameters and then call the Class:

```
$registration = new Register();
$notice[] =      $registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
```

So if the form faced any error such as:

```
already registerd username error
already exists email address error
```

It should simply take back an `error message` and show it to users by these code on the index page:

```
if(isset($notice['email_validation'])) {
    echo "
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['email_validation'].".
        </div>
    ";
}
if(isset($notice['username_exists'])) {
    echo "
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['username_exists'].".
        </div>
    ";
}
if(isset($notice['email_exists'])) {
    echo "
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['email_exists'].".
        </div>
    ";
}
if(isset($notice['success_message'])) {
    echo "
        <div class='alert alert-success'>
            <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['success_message'].".
        </div>
    ";
}
```

**Question:**

The problem with this code is that the error messages does not pop up when a user enters information despite of the rules. However it still adds new row to table correctly.

So now the question is "Why the errors does not show up on page when users enters wrong information? Which part I made a mistake"

Comment: Is this production code? It looks like you have the right idea here, but you're also re-inventing a lot of wheels here, and that can be problematic if this absolutely needs to be secure. No matter what you're doing you **must** [properly hash any user passwords](https://www.phptherightway.com/#security) or you're exposing your users to huge risk. Even if this is a test project take the extra five minutes to do it right. That way if your project succeeds and gets deployed you won't get burned.

Answer (score 1):

There's an diffrence between `$notice` and `$this->notice`. `$notice` is a local var and `$this->notice` is a class var. In your case, you only create a local var, assign a value, but return the still empty class var.

To fix this, simply replace it with `$this->notice[..] = ...`.

But there are also other logical issues. Why does `CheckUname` creates a user? It would be the task of `NewAdmin` to call `CheckUname`. Also you could merge the two database queries into one, asking, if there's a entry with the username or the password. There's more to fix/change, but that would be part of Code Review

Comment: I don't understand which part I should change. Do mean `getNotice()` method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your $notice variable will always be "not set" below. All the variables will be reset after post processing. However, you can redirect to the url that has the $notice variable. For instance, after all the processing you can:

```
redirect_to('index.php?notice=1');
```

where redirect_to is a function that takes a url.

```
function redirect_to($path){
    die("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=0;URL='".$path."' />");
}
```

And then in your index.php, you can check the notice variable if it is set. There are different ways on how to do this though.

EDIT:

```
function redirect_to($path){
   header("Location: " . $path);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you create a redirect through HTML and not through the PHP `header()` call?